# Random samples from custom distribution with rejection method

Tags: r, self-study, random-variable

Could you please suggest a method (in R) to produce random numbers from:

$P(X=x)= -\frac{1}{log(1-p)} \frac{p^x}{x}$

≡  ∈ Θ = (0,1),  = 1,2...

I am very new to this and completely lost..

Comment: See the package `vcdExtra`, and the `rlogseries` function in that package (which is on CRAN).

Comment: I need to clarify that no extra packages should be used

Comment: Thanks for updating the question and adding `self-study` as well. It makes what you're asking for clearer. What methods for random number generation have you covered/are in your textbook etc?

Comment: Thank you for your time!! We have covered Inverse method, rejection method and composition method.

Comment: Consider rejection sampling from a discretized version of a Gamma$(\epsilon)$ distribution with $\epsilon \approx 0.$  This would be efficient and relatively easy to implement.  It's not a simple programming exercise, though.

Comment: My advice would also to be to consider rejection method. If you don't need it to be particularly efficient at all values of p, the geometric (number of trials version, and with parameter 1-p rather than p) is an obvious first majorizing function ('envelope') to consider, but be aware that a modification of it might be needed in some situations (as should become clearer if you examine it). A suitable mixture of shifted geometrics should generally be pretty efficient if you want to implement something for general use.

Comment: Do you have specific values of p you need this to work well for?

Comment:  ∈ Θ = (0,1) .that's all the info I have!